# exact online api returning part of request

Tags: python, rest, exact-online

I'm trying to request a bunch of data concerning hours worked from exact online using python. To do so I'm using this https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=ProjectTimeTransactions .

According to this list it's possible to request PriceFC,Project,ProjectCode, but I'm not able to see those (other values such as division, employee, status, etc I can retrieve).

I do this with:

```
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + bearer_token}
query_args = {}
result = requests.get('https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/' + CURRENT_DIVISION + '/project/TimeTransactions' ,
                      headers=headers,
                      params=query_args)
pprint.pprint(result.text)
```

I've also tried doing so with expressly selecting PriceFC,Project,ProjectCode using:

- query_args = {'select':'PriceFC,Project,ProjectCode'}
- query_args = {'$select':'PriceFC,Project,ProjectCode'}
- headers['select'] = 'PriceFC,Project,ProjectCode'
- headers['$select'] = 'PriceFC,Project,ProjectCode'

None of these return PriceFC,Project,ProjectCode. How do I retrieve this information?

Comment: And that information is there in Exact Online?

Comment: Yes, I can access it and it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two TimeTransactions, one for project and one for manufactering. Mixing them up results in incomplete results.